# How to use secrets and configmaps from spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, spinnaker

I'm deploying my application into Google Kubernetes Engine, but I need to use `Secrets`/`ConfigMaps` in the configuration of `ADD SERVER GROUP` in spinnaker.

How can I do that?

Should I keep the keys or the data of secrets in spinnaker machine and give the pat of that directory or should I give the GitHub URL?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am getting no reference"*?

Comment: I mean to say I could not find find any document explaining how to use secrets and configmaps. can you please help me?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue myself. I can't find anything about how to have a secret inside of my application's repository and use it with spinnaker. We've solved this with kubernetes-deploy from shopify, but that will be replaced with spinnaker.